# Bot keeps spamming in the welcome channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a Discord bot in discord.js with a welcome message but whenever someone joins the bot keeps spamming.

Here's my code

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (newMember) => {
    client.on("message", (msg) => {
        // IMPORTANT NOTE: Make Sure To Use async and rename bot to client or whatever name you have for your bot events!
        if (msg.author.bot) return;
        const welcomeChannel = newMember.guild.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name.includes("welcome"));
        welcomeChannel.send(`**${newMember.user.username}** had joined ${msg.guild.name}`);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you have a message event inside another event? That's not how events work

Comment: Next time, [read the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) before asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever someone joins your Guild the bot will create a listener for the `message` event. Let's say 2 people join your server; 2 `message` listeners are created and when someone sends a message in any channel, your bot will send the welcome message twice. This number is increased every time a new member joins.

**You should never listen to an event within an event.**

In this case, you don't need the `message` event at all, just `guildMemberAdd`.

---

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.includes('welcome'));

    if (!welcomeChannel) return console.error('Welcome channel not found.');

    welcomeChannel.send(`**${member.user.tag}** had joined ${member.guild.name}`).catch(console.error);
});
```